# how to save a string into a list of characters but also able to print that list out in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python and I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

For example:

```
a = "string"

s = list(a)
```

That turns `"string"` into `['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']`

But how can I reverse the list and print out `"gnirts"` without using the built in reverse method from Python.

Comment: Is this a homework that you shouldn't use builtin methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is just reverse your string using [slice notation](https://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-python):

```
a = 'string'
print(a[::-1])
```

You can also convert your string to a list, then reverse it and finally join all together by:

```
a = 'string'
print(''.join(list(a)[::-1])
```

You can also use a for loop which is a little bit more complicated:

```
inversed_a = ''

for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1):
    inversed_a += a[i]
```

then `inversed_a` will be `'gnirts'`

Comment: @Arman, actually the other guy edited his answer when he was downvoted, and we ended up providing the same response.

Comment: In my opinion your previous answer was correct too , because OP himself first converted string to list.

Comment: @Arman, thanks for your comment, I have updated my question providing my previous response and another using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

To get string characters in reversed order no need to convert the string into list - use *reversed slicing*:

```
a = "string"
print(a[::-1])
```

The output:

```
gnirts
```

Some helpful topic about ***Python's slice notation***:

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Is there also a way for me to use loops to do this?

Comment: @lg713, technically - yes, but for such simple case it would be overcomplicated